# Recover from KBD from Mac

Tags: boot, boot-issues

My Raspberry Pi went into KBD Mode displaying this message after I unplugged it directly without shutting it down after it stopped responding. How can I fix this from a Mac, which is the only laptop I have access to, or access the files and filesystem from the SD Card to recover the files as if I just plug it in I only see about 10 files?

I cannot post a photo as I don't have enough reputation but it seems to be the standard error message that is associated with KBD.

Answer (score 3):

You're only seeing 10 files because the Mac is mounting the FAT32 partition that holds the Raspberry Pi's bootstrap code and kernel images.

The [Raspbian images shipped by the Pi Foundation](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) split the SD card up into two partitions: the aforementioned FAT32 partition holding kernels and bootstrap code, and an EXT4 partition that holds the actual Linux filesystem, including all user data.

Mac OS X doesn't support the EXT4 filesystem natively, so you can't mount the partition directly and retrieve the data; however, take a look at [the accepted answer on this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/a/53550/116928) for a possible way to mount it.

Comment: Similar to the SuperUser question, I am also using MacFUSE and fuse-ext2, and it works fine for mounting Linux ext* filesystems. I would also suggest to use OSXFuse, as MacFUSE doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this and get the following errors:
    Downloads $ sudo fuse-ext2 ./2013-05-29-wheezy-armel.img /Volumes/wheezy -o ro
    fuse-ext2: version:'0.0.7', fuse_version:'27' [main (../../fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2.c:324)]
fuse-ext2: enter [do_probe (../../fuse-ext2/do_probe.c:30)]
fuse-ext2: Error while trying to open /Users/matthew/Downloads/2013-05-29-wheezy-armel.img (rc=2133571347) [do_probe (../../fuse-ext2/do_probe.c:34)]
fuse-ext2: Probe failed [main (../../fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2.c:340)]